# ¿Como puedo dividir todas las columnas de un dataframe entre un numero en Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo un dataframe con mas de 75 columnas y solo una fila, mas o menos así
[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito dividir todas las columnas entre el numero **29**"
El output esperado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Conocen alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Divide el dataframe por el número:

```
df = df / numero
```

Vease:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[45.12, 172.36, 763.3, 938.3]])
df = df/29
print(df)
#           0         1         2          3
# 0  1.555862  5.943448  26.32069  32.355172
```

Comment: Pero tendria que agregar las 75 columnas cuando creo el Dataframe

Comment: El código de la respuesta es un ejemplo para recrearlo. Parto de la premisa de que tú ya tienes el DataFrame hecho (ya lo saques de un csv o lo inicialices con datos que recibas de internet, etc.).